# Why isn't variable displaying in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML code with directive Angular JS:

```
<div ng-controller="SongsController">{{genres}}</div>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('SongsController', ['$scope', '$http', 'songsService', 'customFunctions', '$timeout', '$activityIndicator', '$confirm', 'genresService', '$filter', 'UploadFilesHash', 'loader', function ($scope, $http, songsService, customFunctions, $timeout, $activityIndicator, $confirm, genresService, $filter, UploadFilesHash, loader) {

genresService.get(function (data) {
            $scope.genres = data;
        });

}]);
```

Comment: Could you post your controller code (the part related to this?)

Comment: do you have `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives in your html?

Comment: Also it will be better if you provide full code of your directive

Comment: this is still not enough to qualify as a [mcve].  Your controller code is showing many injections that are not related to the issue;  you still aren't showing where your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` are defined, and you haven't provided any samples of the data you are trying to render.

Comment: I delete all from HTML and leave this(see question)